# Need to send records individually using Apache NiFi to Kafka

Tags: apache-kafka, schema, apache-nifi, avro

I am reading records in a stream/batch format from the nifi-user log file itself for a test scenario and using ConvertRecord nifi processor to convert to Avro format and then publishing to a kafka topic using PublishKafka_2_0 processor. I am also using Schema registry for schema conformation. So now when the records are dumped onto kafka its is been done as a single array and not individual records. Is there a way to break records into an individual entity. I have already tried Split records processor it doesnt seem to do the intended. Is there another way to achieve it.

--Updated

Comment: Are you splitting before Avro conversion? Is your schema an array?

Comment: I had used the SplitRecord processor where in the split and coversion both are been done as i use a grok reader to read and AvroRecordSetWrite to write in Avro.. but it didn't work.

Comment: Which Kafka processor are you using you to publish the records?

Comment: Also please describe the original format of your data and how it is being converted to Avro and what the schema is.

Comment: I have updated the answer based on your comments and here is the schema that is been used for the same:
{
  "type": "record",
  "name": "nifi_logs",
  "namespace": "xyz.abc",
  "fields": [
    {
      "name": "timestamp",
      "type": "string"
    },
    {
      "name": "level",
      "type": "string"
    },
    {
      "name": "thread",
      "type": "string"
    },
    {
      "name": "class",
      "type": "string"
    },
    {
      "name": "message",
      "type": "string"
    },
    {
      "name": "stackTrace",
      "type": "string"
    }
  ]
}

Answer (score 0):

For proper feedback please share a flow that reproduces the problem, however the following steps hopefully do what you are looking for:

- Split your message directly before sending to Kafka, and confirm that the split actually succeeded
- Try publish Kafka record 2.0 instead of Publish Kafka 2.0
- Set the maximum message size to 1 byte instead of 1MB?!